# How to disable the product using sql

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am having the list of product sku. By using that Sku I need to disabled that products using a MySQL query. I don't know table structure and how to do it using sql query. Please advice me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To disable product by using SKU. First of all find the `attribute_id` value for `status`.

```
Go to Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
```

Then you will find list of attributes in Attribute Code Box type status and click on Search you will find status attribute click on it you will be redirected to edit page there in the `url` you will find

```
catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/**XXX**/key/
```

Copy the **Attribute id** and paste it in the SQL query run it in `phpMyAdmin`.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int a, catalog_product_entity b
SET a.value = "2"
WHERE b.entity_id = a.entity_id
AND b.sku LIKE '%SKU%'
AND a.attribute_id = **XXX**
```

After running the query Login to your admin and go to

- `System > Cache Management - >  Clear Cache`
- `System > Index management > Rebuild Catalog Index`

Comment: Back up your database first!

Answer (score 2):

> **Magento 2 [EE] SQL Query as follows below.**

To disable products by using SKU. Find the **attribute_id** value for status.

> **Step 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code = 'status';
```

> **Step 2**

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int a, catalog_product_entity b
    SET a.value = "2"
    WHERE b.row_id = a.row_id
    AND b.sku LIKE '%SKU%'
    AND a.attribute_id = **attribute_code**
```

***If you like the answer please give thumbs up.***

*Kindness is the best form of humanity.*

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer here for posterity if somebody stumbles across this as i did:
(magento 2.3.5 solution)

```
UPDATE 
    catalog_product_entity_int AI 
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute A ON AI.attribute_id = A.attribute_id
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity P ON AI.entity_id = P.entity_id
SET AI.value = "2"
WHERE 
    P.sku IN ( ... ) AND 
    A.attribute_code = 'status' AND 
    A.entity_type_id = 4
```