# How to disable all products in Magento 2 using MySQL query?

Tags: magento2, database, enable-disable, mysql8

I've a custom cron scheduler which will automatically enable the products and also update the stock.

I need to disable all the products before executing my custom cron scheduler.

Can this be achieved through mysql script?

Thanks

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192346/how-to-disable-the-product-using-sql

Comment: Thanks @Mehran

With few changes in the condition, the query is working